# Show type of each result in GHCi

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

How can I show type of resulting expression in GHCi after each command?
For example, instead of

```
ghci> "hello" ++ " world"
"hello world"
```

I want to see

```
ghci> "hello" ++ " world"
"hello world" :: String
```

or at least

```
ghci> "hello" ++ " world"
"hello world" :: [Char]
```

REPLs for other languages provide such behavior by default. But I can't find [proper ghci option](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#verbosity-options) for such behavior. It also will be ok for me to just print type of `it` after executing every command. But I didn't find a way how to call my commands after each ghci command. Well, sensible command: `let ... = ...` doesn't have result (though it would be nice to print type of defined variable).
So what are the ways to show type of result automatically after each command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `:set +t` to `.ghci`.

From [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-options):

```
+t
    Display the type of each variable bound after a statement is entered at the prompt.
    If the statement is a single expression, then the only variable binding will be for
    the variable ‘it’.
```